# ORA-00906:"missing left parenthesis" in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

When I tried to create this table, this error appeared me and I don't know why

```
CREATE TABLE Empregado(
    cod_empregado INTEGER,
    cod_supervisor INTEGER,
    cod_armazem INTEGER,
    nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    morada VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    salario_semanal NUMERIC(*,2) NOT NULL,
    formacao VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Empregado_cod_empregado PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Empregado_cod_supervisor FOREIGN KEY(cod_supervisor) 
    REFERENCES Empregado(cod_supervisor),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Empregado_cod_armazem FOREIGN KEY(cod_armazem) REFERENCES 
    Armazem(cod_armazem)
);
```

And this is the output
Error report -
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: yes ! 
but the problem is not there

Answer (score 3):

The issue that throws out the error you are seeing is caused by the PRIMARY KEY constraint: you didn't state WHICH column is the primary key. The PK column must be in parentheses; the opening parenthesis is missing (along with the rest), and that is the first syntax violation Oracle sees.

After you fix that, you will get another error, on the first foreign key, because you are referencing the wrong table (or if it should reference the same table you are creating, you are referencing the wrong COLUMN).